# Mathematics vs. Math Educators

Tags: discussion

I have noticed something, the way I ask Questions or Answer Questions, they are well received in "Mathematics Educators" but are downvoted in "Mathematics" group. So I was wondering is there a difference in the way "Practitioners" look at Math vs. the way "Educators" look at Math? I know while Educators try to make it more connected to Life, easy to understand, Practitioners maybe try to Abstract it towards Purity. Is it a known thing, have you noticed this difference. I am Learning to Teach and thought this might be important...

Answer (score 9):

> the way I ask Questions or Answer Questions, they are well received in "Mathematics Educators" but are downvoted in "Mathematics" group.

I do not believe your experience is because of a difference between mathematicians (whether pure or applied) and mathematics educators.  I believe it is because of a difference in the "Mathematics Stack Exchange" (MSE) and "Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange" (MESE) communities.

MSE started around 2010; MESE started around 2014.  MSE has around 760,000+ registered users; MESE has around 12,000+.

MSE is an older and larger site.  One major problem it has is the low quality of contributions (especially from those looking for quick answers to their homework).  So the main concern of some MSE users is improving site quality.

MESE is not even out of public beta.  One major problem it has is the low quantity of contributions.  (Practically no one goes to MESE for quick answers to their homework.)  So the main concern of some MESE users is attracting more users.

Comment: Wait, what? MESE is in its 7th year of "beta" status? Pray tell more. And what's the effective difference (in terms of functionality, etc.) between beta and regular sites?

Comment: @RyanG If you go to the math educators stackexchange site, it says at the top "Mathematics Educators beta." My understanding is that the site would have "graduated" out of beta if it had higher activity.

Comment: @ChrisCunningham, do you know how high our activity would need to go to get out of beta?

Comment: @SueVanHattum It seems like it at least originally was based on the metrics at Area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-educators .

Comment: @RyanG, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/177408.

Comment: On leaving beta, relevant info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/177408

Comment: Well, if 7 years gets you out of beta, then we should be out soon. We're great on all but number of questions per day. And it seems SE is recognizing that some sites are smaller.

Comment: @RyanG. if I understand correctly, the amount of rep needed for various privileges is lower on a beta site than on a site that's graduated.

Comment: @JW I only skimmed the links, but get the impression that it (the answer to my queries, as well as what you surmise about the rep-privileges) is...complicated (noncommittal?). Separately, from Joel's above links (thanks): [Monica argues passionately](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1745).

Comment: @SueVanHattum 7 years isn’t the magic number to get out of beta, it was a one time thing. For instance, Politics SE has been in beta for more than seven years (I think it’s approaching 9), but is still in beta.

Comment: [\*pops champagne\*](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/726/372) ?