# We're leaving beta!

Tags: discussion, public-beta

On December 16, 2021, Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange ([along with 58 other sites](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/16/congratulations-are-in-order-these-sites-are-leaving-beta/?cb=1)) is leaving beta!  (I'm sorry, I couldn't think of a question for this post.)

Comment: Additional information can be found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/177408

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this.

Comment: Congrats, to all here!  Much deserved!

Comment: Congrats ME.SE!

Comment: As a person who is not here every day to maintain this community, I am grateful to the people who are.  Meta made the right decision in recognizing how valuable and healthy this space is.